# Installer Stub for large file

Tags: installation, stub, resume-download, download-manager

We've got a large program to install (1Gb) packaged into an installer already.
Is there any easy way to use a download manager to ensure that our clients can download without any issues.

I was thinking a simple stub that just downloads the file then executes once done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various bootstrappers that support web downloads.

[InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com)

[dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/)